# jQuery конфликт версий

Tags: javascript, jquery

при переносе файлов сайта с одного хостинга на другой, некоторые файлы на сайте не работают корректно. В интернете нашел информацию, касательно каких-то "конфиктов jquery", но толком не понял что сделать. 
Сайт где корретно все работае - [НОРМАЛЬНЫЙ](http://postel2.perfect-store.top/)
и проблемный сайт -  -[ПРОБЛЕМНЫЙ](http://postelsatin.com.ua)
Не работает добавление в корзину, сама корзина и слайдер
Изнений на сайт не вносил

Comment: Странно что и на старом сайте всё работает с кучей ошибок в консоли

Comment: Консоль говорит у вас не хватает файлов, либо прав на те папки, где эти файлы лежат (http://postelsatin.com.ua/libs/owl-carousel/owl.theme.default.min.css и т.д.\)